# How to replace children in Qt Model-View framework?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I am using `QAbstractItemModel` to implement my model. I have a parent item and want to replace its child items with another set of child items. Before and after replacing, what model methods should I use? Or what model signals should I emit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the model with parent being the QModelIndex of the parent items and count being the amount of child items to add:

```
beginRemoveRows(parent, 0, rowCount(parent));
//remove from data
endRemoveRows();
beginInsertRows(parent, 0, count);
//add rows into data
endInsertRows();
```